# How do i replicate a webrequest with custom parameters (not postdata, not url parameters)?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, fiddler

**Context:**

Hi everyone, i am trying to simulate a query on this [website](http://sefaznet.ac.gov.br/sefazonline/servlet/hpfsincon), but i am failing to do so.

I am using `C#` and a custom self developed library to Wrap the WebRequests actions making it easier to simulate `Posts and Gets` for Strings and Bitmaps.

Also, i'm using [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) Web Debugger to debug the web requests of the service

**How to test the service Yourself:**

1. Link to the [service](http://sefaznet.ac.gov.br/sefazonline/servlet/hpfsincon)
2. Use this document on the first white box : 04034872000121
3. Write the captcha and click at "Consultar"

Thats it.

**Problem:**

After Debuging the requests with fiddler, and replicated everything on code (Cookies, Origin, Host, Postdata with a huge json and so on).

The request for the query, still not working, it redirects me to the home page again, instead of querying the document. (I am allowing "AutoRedirect" on web request object).

The only parameter that i'm not beeing able to replicate is the : `GxAjaxRequest: 1`

Here is the Fiddler debug feedback of the request:

```
POST http://sefaznet.ac.gov.br/sefazonline/servlet/hpfsincon?0898a16d81a4e94896958b17b52f252d,gx-no-cache=1354713117196 HTTP/1.1
Host: sefaznet.ac.gov.br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1337
Origin: http://sefaznet.ac.gov.br
GxAjaxRequest: 1 **Weird Parameter. I've never saw it before.**
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://sefaznet.ac.gov.br/sefazonline/servlet/hpfsincon
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: GX_SESSION_ID=vSLRLKed3eXJGMBorGepVtQkJOQ1I3o0EBUVzT0g%2BI8%3D;     JSESSIONID=af2ba968b7889ec8869caaaba281

vNUMDOC=04034872000121&cfield=chin&BUTTON1=Consultar&BTN_VOLTAR=Retornar&GXState=%7B%22_EventName%22%3A%22E'VISUALIZADADOS'.%22%2C%22_EventGridId%22%3A44%2C%22_EventRowId%22%3Aundefined%2C%22nRC_Duplicados%22%3A%220%22%2C%22CAPTCHA1_Reloadimagetext%22%3A%22Obter%20nova%20imagem!%22%2C%22CAPTCHA1_Validationresult%22%3A1%2C%22GX_FocusControl%22%3A%22vNUMDOC%22%2C%22GX_AJAX_KEY%22%3A%2264FFFF0AFF7A4DFF2655FFFFFF26FF77%22%2C%22AJAX_SECURITY_TOKEN%22%3A%221a9634f566dcd40d12bb8146fd7ff6edca12ae737a3743d79b4b826c3bd4a604%22%2C%22GX_CMP_OBJS%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22sCallerURL%22%3A%22%2Fsefazonline%2Fservlet%2Fhpfsindado%3FeTlFtl5mBgEOtpLCt8Q02bMjmN3K93hV7i2Uxq_rHv0%3D%22%2C%22GX_RES_PROVIDER%22%3A%22com.genexus.webpanels.GXResourceProvider%22%2C%22GX_THEME%22%3A%22GeneXusX%22%2C%22_MODE%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Mode%22%3A%22%22%2C%22IsModified%22%3A%221%22%2C%22MESSAGE_Width%22%3A%22100%22%2C%22MESSAGE_Height%22%3A%22100%22%2C%22MESSAGE_Show%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22MESSAGE_Title%22%3A%22Title%22%2C%22MESSAGE_Message%22%3A%22This%20is%20the%20message%22%2C%22MESSAGE_Type%22%3A%22alert%22%2C%22MESSAGE_Icon%22%3A%22info%22%2C%22MESSAGE_Cls%22%3A%22%22%2C%22MESSAGE_Position%22%3A%22t%22%2C%22MESSAGE_Duration%22%3A1%2C%22MESSAGE_Visible%22%3A1%2C%22CAPTCHA1_Width%22%3A%22140%22%2C%22CAPTCHA1_Height%22%3A%2239%22%2C%22CAPTCHA1_Visible%22%3A1%7D&
```

**Question:**

How do i actually replicate/add this parameter to my webrequest via code ?

Is there any way to do so ?

By the way, the site messes alot with scripts which was hard to "figure out" the origin from most parameters used on the requests.

I hope someone might help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out.

The problem was that i've had to add a custom header to each request.

```
webRequest.Headers.Add ("customheadertext and value");
```

Now fiddler shows correctly my new request, with the added header

```
POST http://sefaznet.ac.gov.br/sefazonline/servlet/hpfsincon?0898a16d81a4e94896958b17b52f252d,gx-no-cache=1354721123208 HTTP/1.1
GxAjaxRequest: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko)   Chrome/13.0.782.107 Safari/535.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://sefaznet.ac.gov.br/sefazonline/servlet/hpfsincon
Host: sefaznet.ac.gov.br
Cookie: GX_SESSION_ID=B8w8AQ4W%2FLzLHIpBor3JwJDQAWGy1xRqCYUMnzF14Yk%3D;     JSESSIONID=c19564cbebfab1911442fd64a0bb
Content-Length: 1291
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```